# How to fix an address issue

Tags: c++, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to solve a Pascal's Triangle problem on Leetcode. I get this error when I run the code.

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000014 at pc 0x000000407875 bp 0x7ffe13bd9300 WRITE of size 4 at 0x602000000014 thread T0.
```

How should I fix it?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {


        vector<vector<int>> tri(numRows);

        vector<int> row;
        row.push_back(1);
        tri.push_back(row);
        row.clear();

        for (int i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
            row[0]=1;
            row[i]=1;
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {

                    row[j] = tri[i-1][j] + tri[i-1][j-1]; 

            }
            tri[i] = row;
            row.clear();
        }
        return tri;

    }
};
```

Comment: What are your inputs for the function?

Comment: After `row.clear();` the number of addressable elements in `row` is zero. You cannot subsequently (_i.e._ in your loop) write to `row[0]` or any other index.  Note also that every element of `tri` is a zero-sized vector, except the value at `tri[numRows]` which has a single element in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `row.clear()`, that wipes the row and sets the length to 0. As a result, when you try accessing `row[0]`, `row[i]`, etc, you're accessing memory that you shouldn't be touching.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
row[0]=1;
row[i]=1;
```

At this point, the `row` vector is empty. So you are writing into thin air.